# Index out of bound error in Corba application

Tags: java

I am trying to understand Java Code which gives an error on compiling that index out of bound. I am trying to figure out why it is giving this error but failed. Can anyone help me that why this code is giving index out of bound error?

```
try {
            ORB orb = ORB.init(args, null);
            POA rootpoa = POAHelper.narrow(orb
                    .resolve_initial_references("RootPOA"));
            rootpoa.the_POAManager().activate();

            ProfilerServant profilerServant = new ProfilerServant(args[4],
                    args[5].equals("true"));
            org.omg.CORBA.Object ref = rootpoa
                    .servant_to_reference(profilerServant);
            Profiler pref = ProfilerHelper.narrow(ref);

            org.omg.CORBA.Object objRef = orb
                    .resolve_initial_references("NameService");
            NamingContextExt ncRef = NamingContextExtHelper.narrow(objRef);

            String name = "Profiler";
            NameComponent path[] = ncRef.to_name(name);
            ncRef.rebind(path, pref);

            orb.run();
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }
```

Here is the ProfilerServant Class
with the constructor

```
public class ProfilerServant extends ProfilerPOA {

boolean cacheEnabled;

ServerParser parser;
HashMap<String, Integer> songCache;
HashMap<String, User> userCache;

ProfilerServant(String fileName, boolean cacheEnabled) {
    this.cacheEnabled = cacheEnabled;
    parser = new ServerParser(fileName);
    songCache = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    userCache = new HashMap<String, User>();
    init();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `args[4]` and `args[5]` are in range?

Comment: don't know. I am now to java .. Its all profilerServant Class. .

Comment: what is the range of args[]  ..

Comment: by default `args` is the array passed to main. `public static void main(String[] args)`

Comment: @Natalia - If that `args` value comes from your `main` method, then the length of `args` (i.e. its "range") is determined by the number of arguments the user provides on the command line.  And that's the problem.  Your program is >>assuming<< that there are at least 6 arguments ... and throwing an exception because that is not correct.

Answer (score 2):

The entry point of a java application is the `main` method.

```
public static void main(String[] args){}
```

`args` is a `String` array of the command line arguments used to run the program.

Assume your main class is `Program.java`.

On the terminal or command prompt, compile the program with `javac Program.java` and run with `java Program /filename true`

The `args` array is: `"java","Program","/filename","true"`

Given `ProfilerServant(String fileName, boolean cacheEnabled)`, you can instantiate `ProfilerServant` as:

```
ProfilerServant profilerServant = new ProfilerServant(args[2],
                args[3].equals("true"));
//This turns to:
ProfilerServant profilerServant = new ProfilerServant("/filename",
                "true".equals("true"));
```

Attempting to access an index out of bounds of `args` will result in `IndexOutOfBounds`.

Answer (score -1):

The code is passing args to profilerServant  class constructor.
make sure initialization of the values of args[4] and args[5] are correct.
check the length of argument args[4].